# Как написать запрос, который удаляет все данные о Марке Лада

Tags: mysql, sql

Даны таблицы
Код машины Название Количество Номер марки
Номер марки Название
Как написать запрос, который удаляет все данные о Марке Лада

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM `название_таблицы` WHERE `название_марки` = 'Лада'
```